# Behavior of CALCULATE inside another CALCULATE function in DAX

Tags: dax

Given these two measures:

```
Measure1 = CALCULATE(CALCULATE(SUM([column]); Filter 1; Filter 2 ); Filter 3; Filter 4 ) 
Measure2 = CALCULATE(SUM([column]); Filter 1; Filter 2; Filter 3; Filter 4 )
```

Why do I obtain different results?

Comment: different how? care to show some example input data and output results?

Comment: It's not simple to show some input because the filters are complicated vue in sql, I thought that Measure1 = Measure2 but visually it's not the same, i'm wondering why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future readers, I'd like to put a non-link-only answer here.

As Marco Russo explains in the article
[Order of Evaluation in CALCULATE Parameters](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/order-of-evaluation-in-calculate-parameters/),
in your `Measure1`, the outer filters `Filter 3` and `Filter 4` will be evaluated first, whereas in `Measure2` all of the filters are evaluated in parallel (and will be combined using AND logic).

If the one of the filters `Filter 1` or `Filter 2` remove any filter context specified by `Filter 3` or `Filter 4` (e.g. using a function like `ALL()`), then you will get a different result than if all the filters were evaluated in parallel.

The examples that Marco Russo give are the following:

```
CALCULATE(
    CALCULATE(
        [MEASURE],
        CUSTOMER[COUNTRY] = "ITALY"
    ),
    ALL( CUSTOMER[COUNTRY] )
)
```

versus

```
CALCULATE(
    CALCULATE(
        [MEASURE],
        ALL( CUSTOMER[COUNTRY] )
    ),
    CUSTOMER[COUNTRY] = "ITALY"
)
```

In the first, we filter down to only the `ITALY` rows just as if the outer filter were not there. In the second, the `ALL()` function strips off the outer filter since it is evaluated afterward and you get rows corresponding to all countries.